# FFT over a fixed and equal numbers

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, python

I've got a vector of $100 000$ numbers. All numbers are equal ($7000$ for example).

- If I perform FFT over this vector, what will I get?
- From my understanding, I should receive a fixed DC line. Is this true?
- Is there any website (i've searched) which can simulate that?

Because I did tried to run FFT with Python `np.fft.rfft` and `np.fft.rfftfreq` and didn't get it...

- What am I missing here?

(My question is derived from a broader perspective, so bear with me...)

Comment: What's the size **N** of the FFT ? If you don't specify , by default it will be equal to the size of the signal.

Comment: Is the problem that the frequency content is not where you expected it to be (i.e. at $f=0$)? Maybe you're forgetting to run `fftshift`?

Comment: Can I please ask you to leave your response towards @Peter K. as a comment rather than an edit to the answer (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This python code:

```
 import numpy.fft
 a = [7000 for i in xrange(100000)]
 fft_a = numpy.fft.fft(a)
 print(fft_a)
```

generates this:

```
[  7.00000000e+08+0.j   0.00000000e+00+0.j   0.00000000e+00+0.j ...,
   0.00000000e+00+0.j   0.00000000e+00+0.j   0.00000000e+00+0.j]
```

which looks correct to me.

I have implemented the same thing in `R` and a different, but similar effect can be observed. This is just numerical inaccuracies.

[image]

---

**R Code Below**

```
#Q31078

#a = [7000 for i in xrange(100000)]

a <- rep(700, 100000)

#fft_a = npf.fft(a)
fft_a <- fft(a)

#for idx in range(0,100000):
#  print(str(np.real(fft_a[idx])) + "," +  str(np.imag(fft_a[idx])))

plot(log(abs(fft_a) + 10^-30),  lwd=1)

points(log(abs(vals[,1]+10^-30)), col="red")

title('FFT of constant data: black R, red Python')
```

Comment: I've done that with your code, but if you look closely at all the items, you'll see that about every 50 items, you don't receive a 0+0.j, but rather a fixed number (that changes every 50 items). something like: 5.458e-09 - 1.674e-08j. I took a picture but cannot upload to a comment...

Comment: @roy.me that's just numerical imprecision.

Comment: Ok, so you mean they have no physical meaning (rather mathematical)? because if I output it to a graph, it does no look like a dc straight line... :0)

Comment: @roy.me : I have compared the Python result with the same thing in R, and they return basically the same issue: numerical inaccuracies for very small coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. Your FFT will compute those DFT values for k=0 to k=99.999 all of which are exactly zero but $X[0] = 7000 \cdot 100000 = 7 \times 10^8 $ for k=0. (the DC)

In order to see why this is the case, we can simply look at the definition of the **DFT** (as **FFT** is nothing but a fast algorithm to compute the result of DFT)

The DFT $X[k]$ of a signal $x[n]$ of length N is:

$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{ x[n] e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk }} ,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~0 \leq n,k \leq N-1 $$

Now assuming the signal $x[n]$ is constant K:
$$x[n] = K ~~~~~~~~~~,~~~~~~ \text{for} ~~~~~~ 0\leq n \leq N-1 $$

The DFT becomes:
$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{ K e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk }} ,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~0 \leq n,k \leq N-1 $$

There are a number of ways to evaluate or interpret this finite sum of a periodic complex exponential sum all of which will yield the following:
$$X[k]=
\begin{cases}
N \cdot K ~~~~, k = 0 \\
0 ~~~~, 1 \leq k \leq N-1 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Please look at Peter K. answer and my comment. I don't get all items to be a 0+0j. every 50 items I receive a fixed real+image number.

Comment: @PeterK already answered your comment. And as he said It's probably a numerical issue (unless you did something wrong). FFT involves a series of multiplications and summations. And those sums can build up a roundoff error at some particular frequency, depending on the numerical quality of the FFT library. I don't use python, but matlab. All I can say is in my application the roundoff error is insignificant for this particular line of code: X = abs(fft(7000*ones(1,100000))); All X[k] are **zero** down to machine precision, for k >= 2 (matlab indices begin from 1)